# jquery $ajax closure

Tags: jquery, ajax, closures

I have the following function that takes this frequency parameter and calls the api, but the parameter frequency is not defined inside the SUCCESS callback and I need it. How to pass that parameter to my callback?

```
 init : function(frequency) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/v1/dashboard',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data : {username : "demo",frequency : frequency},
        success: function(data) {
            dashboard_hander.set_data(data.dashboard);
                            //here frequency is undefined

        }
    });
},
```

EDIT 2 =====

It works by defining parameters = {username : "demo",frequency : frequency};
outside of the $.ajax and passing as data object, or defining frequency in a higher scope, like:

```
 var dashboard_hander = {
frequency : "",
init : function(frequency) {
    this.frequency = frequency;

       ...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define it at a higher scope.

```
   init : function(frequency) {
        var myData = {username : "demo",frequency : frequency};
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/v1/dashboard',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data : myData,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(myData.frequency);
                dashboard_hander.set_data(data.dashboard);
                                //here frequency is undefined

            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: The success callback is triggered after the init function is executed, but works because myData is an object. thks!!

Answer (score 2):

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/B2h8m/2/
And here is its code:

```
var test = {init : function(frequency) {
    (function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/v1/dashboard',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data : {username : "demo",frequency : frequency},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(frequency);

            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert(frequency);

            }
        });
    })();
}}
test.init(10);
```

Addtional function wrapping $.ajax will create a closure and that way you will get an access to frequency.

**EDIT:**
Besides, strange that you have it undefined at that place. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/B2h8m/4/) demo. It is using the same code you have. And works fine. Additional function I've added is not needed as success callback function will create a closure also. Except that you are showing not the same code you have a problem with and in your code success is defined something like this:

```
success: successHandlerFunctionName
```

In that case you may change it to:

```
success:function(data) {successHandlerFunctionName(data, frequency);}
```

where frequency will be taken from closure

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `frequency` *is* defined, as it is kept by the closure. It can disapear only if you change it after the ajax call.

[Demonstration with this code :](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/frequency/index3.html)

```
<script>
var obj = {
    init : function(frequency) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index2.html',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        data : {username : "demo",frequency : frequency},
        success: function(data) {
            alert('frequency:' + frequency);
        }
    });
}};
obj.init(33);
</script>
```